# Accessing a .mdf SQL Server file using JDBC in Java?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I am trying to access and read data from a `.mdf` Microsoft SQL Server file (located on a remote server) inside a Java application running locally.

I have a SQL Server JDBC driver installed and it's on my `classpath` but I still cannot seem to access the file, I get the following error:

> The connection to the host PD-SQLTEST, named instance sqlexpress failed.
>   Error: "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out"

I am defining the connection URL as follows:

```
String URLSqlServer ="jdbc:sqlserver://PD-SQLTEST\\SQLEXPRESS; databaseName=AOMLive";
```

The `.mdf` is called `AOMLive.mdf`

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here? Does the SQL Server Database on the remote server have to be running for me to access?

Answer (score 5):

You must have the SQL Server running; JDBC cannot read that file directly.